VS Code program run command is absurdly placed after terminal prompt
I'm using code runner extension. But recently when running code, the terminal opens and the running command is absurdly placed after terminal prompt for the first time in a new terminal. The problem occurs only when the terminal is started for first time. Running code again in the same terminal doesn't cause the problem until I kill the terminal and then run code again.
Running code in first terminal startup.
It seems like there are a sequence of whitespace in between terminal prompt PS D:\VisualStudioCodes> and the command > python -u "d:\VisualStudioCodes\Python\Programs\Hello.py" .
After first program is run, the next command gets properly placed as it should be in the same terminal.
Second time code is run in the same terminal.

I also noticed the right side the terminal is getting no text field sometimes when code is run. I selected the terminal text to make the portion visible: Wasted right portion of terminal.
Things I tried but didn't work:

I deleted %USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions\formulahendry.code-runner-0.12.2 and reinstalled the code runner extension.

I enabled/disabled different VS Code terminal settings.

I deleted PSReadline module folder and installed v2.3.5 but nothing works. Currently I'm using PSReadline v2.0.0



what if you switch to cmd shell instead of powershell?

@starball cmd works fine. But I want to use PowerShell because it is more versatile than cmd.
